# Cronjob and PHP working together?

Tags: php, bash, cron, cron-task

I wrote a PHP script that push a CSV file into a database. I want to do this automatically every minute. I know there is a way via cron on Linux but I don't know anything about bash and think cron can't give my PHP file a callback, so I can show a progress bar for the user to see the timer interval. What do I do?

Comment: What user? If you want to do this automatically on the server every minute, who would be looking at it and why?

Comment: Its like a preview for some admins to look what happens in the job and which table is updated in the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter your jobs using `crontab -e`. If your default editor is vi, I recommend to change it nano using `export EDITOR=nano` because it is easy to use for starters.

Every line of the crontab file represents a job. The first 5 tokens are : minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week respectively, the last one is command so in your case first 5 tokens will be * * * * * that means run this job every minutes when the second is '00'.

You can call your php files directly using this command : `php /var/www/cron.php &` or using a browser `wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/cron.php` If you use first one you cannot use some $_SERVER variables but if you use second one, it is like a real browser.

In your case you can use like this :

```
* * * * * wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/cron.php
```

Comment: OKEY nice! Thanks at all, but one more question. My provider does support cronjobs every hour. Can I put a bash file into the root so that will be loaden? Or are there exist some other application/ideas to do my thing? My provider is Strato/DE and im using windows so its difficult to try cronjobs

Comment: Do you have access to server using SSH? If you can execute bash files, you can using like this : [http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sleep-bash-scripting/](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sleep-bash-scripting/) or create a php file which sleeps 1 minute on every loop and executes 1 hour long

Answer (score 0):

to add a cron and make it run every minute, type `crontab -e` and add the following line

```
* * * * * command you need executing
```

example:

```
* * * * * ls -l /home/ > /usr/local/users.txt
* * * * * df -h > /tmp/filesystem_usage.txt
* * * * * service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this for a starter: http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/

Also remember that cronjobs don't support all $_SERVER vars like 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' and 'HTTP_HOST', so try to avoid them, or use a workaround.

Some 'callback' possibilities:
- Let your script trigger another script
- Redirect the output of your cron to an another bash script
- ...